# How to avoid accidental deletions of databases in Lotus Notes?

Tags: database, lotus-notes

I have always worried about users deleting lotus notes databases by accident. We had one such case last week and I want to know how we can lock the databases so that users cannot delete them.

Is there a way in Lotus Notes - either at the Db level or server level where we can set up the database so that only the administer of the db or the user with Manager access can delete the database?

Answer (score 3):

A user can only delete a server-based database if the user has Manager rights to the database. Just confirm that your users do not have Manager rights (use the "Effective Access" button on the ACL dialog window to check this).

Answer (score 1):

the good practice is to have separate ID for such Hardcore operations, like Deletions, users deletions and so on, so if you want to delete something, switch to another id and then delete, other time you are like regular user. without MANAGER access :)